# Entity Framework - re-assigning variable

Tags: entity-framework

We're using Entity Framework 6.4.4 in a project. We've started to notice that we're getting leaking connections and running out of "connections from the connection pool".

I have a question if the following is ok or could it create any weird connection issues.

Say I have the following:

```
var myObject = await _context.Objects.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

// ...

myObject = await _context.Objects.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == myObject.Id);
```

Does re-assigning the variable like this lead to any database connection leaking issues? We had a non-tracking entity assigned and then later changed to a tracked entity in our code.

Thanks

Comment: No this will not cause you any problems. Running out of connection in the pool probably means your pool is too small or you are not disposing your db contexts.

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for the info... another question, if I have an Azure App Service scaled out to 6 instances, does each instance maintain it's own connection pooling?  So if we have a default of 100 pool size, would the pool size be 600 due to 6 instances?  Or am I thinking about it wrong?

Comment: I see this in the Microsoft documentation:

Connections are pooled per process, per application domain, per connection string and when integrated security is used, per Windows identity. Connection strings must also be an exact match; keywords supplied in a different order for the same connection will be pooled separately.

So it sounds like each app service would manage it's own connection pool then?

Comment: Add more info: which DBMS are you using, show the connection string.

Comment: There is [workaround](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling#pool-fragmentation-due-to-many-databases).

Comment: A Managed Instance of MS Sql Server hosted in Azure.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov We're also using Authentication=Active Directory Device Code Flow in our ConnectionString if that matters